# Is it likely that one I2C device is interfering with communication to other devices?

Tags: i2c

I have two I2C devices on a single bus, with different addresses.  Let's call them device A and B.  Device A always works, no problem.  Device B only works (means responds to I2C messages) either if device A is disconnected, or if I initialise (means setting calibration coefficients - hard to know why this would make a difference)  device A before trying to communicate with device B.

Weirder still, device B is less accurate when device A is plugged in.  It still works, but I have more dropouts (device unable to get a measurement).

Does anyone have experience of anything similar happening?  Devices are of a similar type and form factor - I don't expect adding device B is changing capacitance of I2C lines or anything like that.

I have measured current draw with and without device A and it doesn't make a big enough difference to suspect a problem with power.

It seems incredible but I am out of ideas, other than redesigning my board to use an I2C multiplexer..

All devices use the same 2.8V supply.

Below is diagram showing how microcontroller is connected to scl/sda lines:
[image: Microcontroller connection to SCL/SDA lines]

And here is how device A is connected.  Device A is connected in the same way.
[image: How ST VL530L0X is connected to microcontroller]

Comment: Could you provide part numbers and datasheets for the devices? Also, could you provide a circuit diagram showing how the devices and the i2c master are connected?

Comment: Post schematics, tell what bus voltage is used, and do all chips use same supply voltage, or different voltages?

Comment: Devices are ST VL530LX (device B) and Sharp gp2ap02vt (device A).  Both TOF proximity sensors.  i have a lot of documentation for them both.  Which bits are you interested in and I'll paste them here.  I have an oscilloscope but can't easily access scl and sda lines on my board.  All devices use same 2.8V supply voltage.

Comment: It seems to me that when you think you have finished the master-slave conversation with device A, device A is still expecting more and therefore when you talk to B, device A somehow clashes either with the message sent to B or clashes with the response from B.

Comment: Data sheet links are needed and also an explanation of what data you are sending to A and what response you think you should get. Ditto for B.

Comment: Which I2C speed is used? Can both chips handle that?

Comment: A quick test would be to reduce the pullups (R13 and R15) to about 470 and see if it gets better or worse.  I don't know what speed you're running, but those 22pF caps might be loading your rise time enough to make the timing marginal, but it should improve with the smaller resistors.  If one of the devices is having trouble pulling them low, on the other hand, making them smaller will worsen the problem, but I suspect the rise time as the more likely culprit.  Taking out those 22pF caps or reducing them may also help.

Comment: About what clk speed are we talking? Some devices uses things like clock stretching which is not properly supported by all devices. Why did you add the caps for the I2C lines? Normally one tries to reduce the capacitance as much as possible to allow for higher clock speeds and respect the specified transition timings.